# Manage workbooks from a Powerpoint macro (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have the following function (VBA code) that I usually use within some Excel macros. It allows me to list the workbooks that I have open and select one of them. It works well.

```
    Function PromptForWorkbook() As String
    Dim N As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim WB As Workbook
    For Each WB In Workbooks
        N = N + 1
        s = s & CStr(N) & " - " & WB.Name & vbNewLine
        'CStr deve converter o número N numa string
    Next WB
    
    N = Application.InputBox( _
    prompt:="Select the source data excel file, by the ID number:" & _
    vbNewLine & s, Type:=1)
    If N <= 0 Or N > Workbooks.Count Then
        PromptForWorkbook = vbNullString
    Else
        PromptForWorkbook = Workbooks(N).Name
    End If
End Function
```

Now, I would like to adapt the code above to run it from a ***PowerPoint macro*** with the same purpose, i.e. have a PowerPoint macro the allow me to select one of the several Excel workbooks I have open. This is what I've done so far but as you may guess it is not working properly. One of the things that work differently in a Powerpoint macro when compared to a Excel macro is the InputBox function which in Excel can return a number while in Powerpoint only returns strings. I adapt that but it still does not work. It doesn't even list the Excel files I have open.

```
Function PromptForWorkbook() As String
    Dim N As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim myString As String
    Dim WB As Workbook
    For Each WB In Workbooks
        N = N + 1
        s = s & CStr(N) & " - " & WB.Name & vbNewLine
        'CStr deve converter o número N numa string
    Next WB
    
    myString = InputBox( _
    prompt:="Select the source data excel file, by the ID number:" & _
    vbNewLine & s)
    N = CInt(myString)
    If N <= 0 Or N > Workbooks.Count Then
        PromptForWorkbook = vbNullString
    Else
        PromptForWorkbook = Workbooks(N).Name
    End If
End Function
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a reference to an instance of Excel ... you can use [`GetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function) to get a reference to an existing instance.

Comment: Can you show me an example with a sample code?

Comment: There's a code snippet in the docs I linked to. Also many similar examples online.

Comment: Instead of N = CInt(myString), use N = Clng(myString)  (Excel expects a long, not an integer; this is likely not the source of trouble, but it's good practice to get the var types right). You'll also want to test for Len(myString) > 0 before doing the conversion, as a blank myString will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning instead of doing that why don't you create a hyperlink in powerpoint from a button or something and then you can manage your workbooks.

Comment: Not sure how exactly works the hyperlink approach to manage workbooks but this function is just a part of the whole macro and if this could work it would give me good insights on how to interact with the Excel file from the powerpoint to many other parts of the macro.